# JSON with comments debugger

Tags: json, firefox

Note: I am just getting into coding.

I've bean trying to make a launch JSON file, but everytime I run it
[Asking for Launch JSONC debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5uvh.png) this pops up and I click the "find" option and I found the Firefox one:

[image: Firefox extension I found]

So I click on the Firefox extension use the tut enter the file location and use the launch option. Then I run it and it's still not working, so I search for a bit and can't find another extension or a solution to my problem - so somebody please help me.

This is what I used:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch index.html",
            "type": "firefox",
            "request": "launch",
            "launch": true,
            "file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html"
        }
    ]
}
```